# Spark Json String to Structure format

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hive

What is the efficient way to convert this string field RelatedParty into separate fields like (FIRSTNAMEBEN,RELATIONSHIPTYPE,DATEOFBIRTH,GeneratedTime) for each CaseID ?

Note: Both columns are in string format and my data size is 80gb.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CaseID|RelatedParty                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123   |"{"123": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"                                                                                                                      |
|456   |"{"456": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCD","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN":"ABCDD","ALIASBEN":"","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party3": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCDDE","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"|
|345   |"{"345": {},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Schema:

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- CaseID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RelatedParty: string (nullable = true)
```

**Excepeted Format:**

```
CaseID  FIRSTNAMEBEN ALIASBEN RELATIONSHIPTYPE DATEOFBIRTH  GeneratedTime

123      ABC          Null    ABC, FGHIJK LMN  7/Oct/1969   2022-01-30 03:09:26
                                                            
456      ABCD         Null    ABC, FGHIJK LMN  7/Oct/1969   2022-01-30 03:09:26
                                                            
456      ABCDD        Null    ABC, FGHIJK LMN  7/Oct/1969   2022-01-30 03:09:26
                                                            
456      ABCDDE       Null    ABC, FGHIJK LMN  7/Oct/1969   2022-01-30 03:09:26
                                                            
345      Null         Null    Null             Null         2022-01-30 03:09:26
```

Sample Data:

```
import spark.implicits._

val values = List(List("123", """"{"123": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"""") ,List("456", """"{"456": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCD","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN":"ABCDD","ALIASBEN":"","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party3": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCDDE","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"""") ,List("345", """"{"345": {},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"""")).map(x =>(x(0), x(1)))

val df = values.toDF ("CaseID","RelatedParty")

df.show
```

I tried to converting this dataframe to Json but its taking huge time to display the count itself some times I am getting this error ( Stage 7 contains a task of very large size (3777 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB)

```
val listValues = df.select("RelatedParty").map(f=>f.getString(0)).collect.toSeq

val df_json = spark.read.json(listValues.toDS())
```

Comment: Please ask a proper question, with a question mark, so others know where the specific question is, and where the considerations start (for example, the "without conversion is also fine" part)

Comment: Your data schema for the last record is incorrect and the `JSON` parser won't be able to read that. You could come up with some kind of `null` value for such records which can be handled later. You can't define a schema for records like `345` because it is treated as a column when you read it and you can't define a dynamic schema for columns. Please fix it and then update the question again in the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's taking so much time because you are using `collect` which brings all the data to the driver and then reads it again.

I think you could use the method `from_json` that given a column with a `string` containing a `JSON` and a schema (`StructType`) it returns you a `Dataframe` with the parsed data

Something similar to this:

```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, from_json}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

  case class RelatedParty(FIRSTNAMEBEN: String, ALIASBEN: String, RELATIONSHIPTYPE: String, DATEOFBIRTH: String)
  
  import spark.implicits._
  val schema = Encoders.product[RelatedParty].schema

  df
    .withColumn("RelatedParty", from_json(col("RelatedParty"), schema))
    .select(f"$RelatedParty.*")
    .as[RelatedParty]
```

You might need to play with the schema as your data seems to contain multiple objects (party1, party2, ...) but they aren't in a list.

Also, your `JSON` has numbers as keys, (`"123": {...` instead of `"id": "123", { ...`) which could make it more complex to parse